# How to build `cmd/compile` itself

Tags: go

## Goal

I want to build [cmd/compile](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/cmd/compile), which is the compile command of go.

## Problem

First, I cloned https://github.com/golang/go to `~/src/github.com/golang/go` and modify codes in `src/cmd/compile`.

Second, I moved to `~/src/github.com/golang/go/src`, and typed `go build -o aaa -i cmd/compile`.

Finally, `aaa` works, but it does not contain anything I modified.

As you know, in anywhere (even if `~/` or `/tmp` or the others), once you type `go build -o aaa -i cmd/compile`, you can get `aaa`.

But, I want make it modify, and build it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Relative paths are assumed to be rooted in `GOROOT` or `GOPATH`, so when you `go build cmd/compile` that's where it will look. If you want to build the one in your working directory you'll need to `go build ./cmd/compile`.

Comment: The golang.org website contains information on how to build the compiler; in short run make.bash or all.bash, or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the package `cmd/compile`, it builds the stdlib package for the current compiler, not the package in the source tree you're in.

If you're planning to work on the compiler itself, you need to bootstrap your own compiler:

- Clone the go source code
- Go to  /src
- Run ./all.bash

That will build the whole source tree, and create a new compiler for you. Once that's done, you have to use the compiler built by this process, which is under `~/src/github.com/golang/go/bin`.

Comment: A faster way is to run `/.make.bash` instead which will skip running the tests.